# Validate if username exist when editing info PHP and SQL

Tags: php, sql, forms

I have a question and I can't find a correct way to solve my problem. 
I have a application where the username is the emailadres. A user can change his/her information on a page called edit.php

I have also a validation in place that is checking if the username exists when editing. This to prevent that user A can edit his username in a username of another existing user. I do this with the following function.

```html
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."'"); 
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>=1) { echo "Exists"; } else { /* update database */ }
```

This works, only now I have a problem. Because the user can edit in the editform not only the USERNAME, but also PHONE, ZIP, CITY. If a user edits his ZIP, CITY or PHONE I will get logically 'exists', because the username is also posted in my editform.

My question: How can I set it up so that the username only is checked when it is different from the current username of the user. For example, if test@test.com (username) edits his information and it remains test@test.com it won't be checked and when the username test@test.com is edited in test123@test.com it will be checked?

I think I need to set up a double check like if mysql_num_rows($sql)>=1 OR ==
Am I right? any help would be great.

Comment: You have to check the email and also the id.

Comment: if you are using email ID as a username then make it disable while editing all information

Comment: If there's a login you should put the user details in cookie , you don't have to check username at $_POST and username shall not be changed this data makes them unique

Answer (score 0):

For the new username to be valid, your check should be: *there is no row with this username, or the row is actually the current user*.

So you need to select the ID in your query (instead of the username, which you don't need) and change your `if` statement to test "no result, or one result with ID = current user ID".

Of course I'm assuming you have an ID as a primary key of your table, and that this ID is stored in the session for the current user.

Also, consider using PDO instead of mysql_query...

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved by doing a verify user with ajax before processing the form, using the SQL query you are currently using:

```
SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$user'
```

If ajax query return "true" or "not empty data", user exist and not is usable, else, user is available for use.

A few months ago I did something similar in a Signup form. On "username" field, if the user is available turns green, if not available, it turns red. The verification is done by changing field.

[Signup Example with verification](http://www.vendobara.com/registrate)

Recommend to use PDO instead of php mysql_query (is deprecated in new PHP versions).